# Android: Linear layout inside scrollview is not showing

Tags: android, scrollview

There are some linear layout inside scrollview as well.
when i install the app on HUAWEI Mate7 it works just fine.
but on Samsung S3 or LG G3 the only thing that shows is background image but when i touch the screen, methods are working. only views are not showing.
here is mainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    android:alpha=".9">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha=".9"
            android:gravity="center">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

inside the linear layout there are 20 of this

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

     <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
         android:src="@drawable/can_pot_com"
         android:scaleType="fitStart"
         android:background="#00ffffff"
         android:cropToPadding="false"
         android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
         android:layout_weight="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/can_pot"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:lines="3"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know what do to!

Comment: post your full xml file here...

Comment: why are you adding xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in your ScrollView

Comment: full xml is more than 30000 character and its not alowed here. @BajiraoShinde

Comment: look my bellow answer

Comment: iv read somewhere that it fixes it but it didn't @Prakhar

Comment: make scrollview height as android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: why are you using  android:alpha=".9"

Comment: Set height of Linear Layout.

Comment: you can use custom listview so you  dont need to write 20 layout in side parent Linear Layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back1"
android:alpha=".9"> <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha=".9"
        android:gravity="center">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related probably with the align and gravity of the layouts; in the LinearLayout child inside the ScrollView, change the `android:gravity="center` by: `android:gravity="top|center"`. Hope it helps.

(And and although it does not give you an error, you can remove the second xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android")

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The LinearLayout inside my ScrollView was not working as expected. The first component of the lineaLayout was not visible.
The reason was android:layout_gravity="center_vertical". Change that to android:layout_gravity="top|center_vertical".

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from your scrollview

```
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: make sure scrollview contain only one child